# How can I make a multi line expanding UTextField or text input using swift iOS (not using UITextView)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

Looking at the behavior of the Apple Messages app, it seems they are using a UITextField for the text input.

The behavior of the placeholder with the cursor appearing at the beginning of the placeholder text (essentially overwriting it) is what I'm basing that assumption on.  There is no placeholder for a UITextView that I'm aware of.

I know I can easily use a UITextView and add a placeholder with different color and code the placeholder disappearing when the user starts typing.  But I was wondering if there is any way at all to program a UITextField that can have it's frame be fixed in width and expand in height wrapping text.

Comment: I do not think Apple Messages app uses a UITextField for its text input.

Comment: It's possible they are using a UITextView with coded placeholder I guess.  Just seems odd the cursor would go to the beginning of the placeholder with the placeholder still there when the textView becomes first responder rather than just removing the text of the placeholder.  I guess I'll just stick with the textView.  Thanks.

Comment: It just occurred to me that maybe the placeholder is a UILabel and not text in the textField that get's removed.  Thanks.  The label is appears only when the textView content is empty and is removed as soon as user starts typing.

Comment: Exactly, I think it's easier to put in a placeholder label than make UITextField adjust frame vertically :)

Answer (score 23):

You can not expand UITextFiled's height.

But you can do this using UITextView ,what you have to do is

Instead of UITextFiled , use UITextView and set ScrollEnabled to false , give UITextView top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint.

Give height constraint to UITextView and set its content hugging priority at low.

now your textview will expand according to text which are insert in it.

Yes, you have to add and manage  placeholder logic manually

Comment: Dear Lord! Thats it. Thanks man! I also had to set height constraint with a low hugging priority for the container view that contains the textview.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the complete working code to make a Multi-line expanding UTextField programmatically:

```
import UIKit


class ExpandableTextFieldViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    // Create a UITextView
    let textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false // Disable scrolling
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16) // Set your preferred font size
        textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8) // Adjust padding
        return textView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add the UITextView to the view
        view.addSubview(textView)

        // Set delegates
        textView.delegate = self

        // Add constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20), // Ensure it doesn't go beyond the bottom of the screen
            // Set an initial height constraint (you can change this to your preferred initial height)
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).withPriority(.defaultLow) // Set content hugging priority to low
        ])
        
        // Customize placeholder text and color
        textView.text = "Enter text here"
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    // MARK: - UITextViewDelegate methods

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // Adjust the height of the UITextView based on its content
        let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: newSize.height).isActive = true
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // Remove placeholder text when the user starts editing
        if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
            textView.text = nil
            textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // Add placeholder text if the user ends editing with an empty field
        if textView.text.isEmpty {
            textView.text = "Enter text here"
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }
}
```